# Exponential Dominating any continuous Function?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, continuity, schwartz-space

Let $f \in C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^k)$.  For most familiar such functions we can find some $\lambda>0$ such that $\lim_{\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}to \infty} e^{-\lambda x} \|f(x)\|_{\mathbb{R}^k} = 0$.  However, can we always find such a $\lambda$?

In other words, is a non-smooth equivalent of the schwartz space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=k=1$ and let's define $f$ as $f(x)=\exp(x^2)$. Then we have that
$$e^{-\lambda x}\left|e^{x^2}\right|=e^{x^2-\lambda x}$$
And it goes to $+\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$ no matter what $\lambda$ is.

Comment: I should rephrase my question as follows:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606911/countable-squence-bounding-all-continuous-funcitons-uniformly