# Countable squence bounding all continuous funcitons uniformly?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

This is rephrasing of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606873/exponential-dominating-any-continuous-function).  Does there exist a sequence of point-wise continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $C(\mathbb{R}^k,[0,\infty))$ satisfying
$$
f_n(x)\leq f_n(z) \mbox{ if } \|z\|\geq \|x\|
$$
such 
that for any $g \in C(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R}^l)$ there exists some $N>0$ such that
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^k} \|f_N(x)g(x)\|<\infty?
$$

Comment: Did you mean $\sup_x \lVert f(x) g(x) \rVert$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by point-wise increasing? $f_n \geqslant f_m$ when $n \geqslant m$?

Comment: Uh...wouldn't $f_1$ be the best one in the sequence for this, and thus the best sequence would just be consisting entirely of the zero function? Or do you need it to be strictly increasing at each point?

Comment: No I mean $f_i(x)<f_i(z)$ if $\|x\|\geq \|z\|$.

Comment: Then you are basically hoping for functions whose growth rate with $x$ decays with $N$, such that if $N$ is large enough then they can dampen out the growth of any $g$? That can't help if $g$ blows up at infinity; $f_N$ will always converge to something nonzero at infinity so the supremum will always be $+\infty$ even as the growth rate slows down.

Comment: But I can $f_N$ to converge faster towards 0?  Do you have a counter-example in mind?

Comment: In 1D, for a fixed $N$, you can let $g(x)=e^x/f_N(x)$ to make $\sup_x |g(x)f_N(x)|=+\infty$, but of course, it's not enough. But maybe the axiom of choice can help?

Comment: How about $f_n\equiv 0$ for all $n?$

Comment: Also, what does "pointwise continuous" mean?

Comment: @AIM_BLB The point is that if $f(x)$ is any continuous function strictly increasing with $\| x \|$ and $g$ blows up at infinity along some ray then $fg$ also blows up at infinity along the same ray, no matter how slow you force $f$ to grow. If $f$ can increase only nonstrictly then you can take $f \equiv 0$ and this is the only way to do it among even nonstrictly increasing $f$. This is because $f$ will have a positive (perhaps infinite) limit along each ray since you have assumed it is increasing.

Comment: Your assumption, that $f_n(x)\leq f_n(z)$ whenever $\Vert z\Vert\geq\Vert x\Vert$ implies that $f_n(x)$ depends only on $\Vert x\Vert$, so the question is essentially one-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If zero values of $f_n$ are allowed then there is an obvious positive answer. Pick some $R>0$ and let $f_1$ be an arbitrary function satisfying the condition such that $f_1(x)=0$  provided $\|x\|\ge R$. For instance, we can put $f_1(x)=\max\{R-\|x\|,0\}$.

If zero values of $f_n$ are not allowed then the answer is negative even for $k=l=1$. Indeed, given any sequence $\{f_n\}\in C(\Bbb R,(0,\infty))$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z$ put $g(n)=|n|/\min_{i\le n} f_i(n)$ and then extend the function $g$ to $\Bbb R$ piecewise-linearly on each interval $[n,n+1]$. Then for each $N$ we have $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_N(n)g(n)\ge \lim_{n\to +\infty} f_N(n)n/f_N(n)=+\infty.$$

I expect it is easy to show that the minimum cardinality of the family $f_n$ bounding all continuous function equals to a small cardinal $\frak d$, well-known in the Modern Set Theory, see [JW], [Va]. It is defined as the smallest size of a set $D$ of functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$ such that for each $g:\omega\to\omega$ there exists a function $f\in D$ such that $f(n)\ge g(n)$ for each $n\in\omega$. Is it easy to see that $\omega_1\le\mathfrak d\le\mathfrak c$. The Martin Axiom implies $\mathfrak d=\mathfrak c$. On the other hand, there are models of ZFC with $\mathfrak d<\mathfrak c$, see [Va].

*References*

[JW] W. Just, M. Weese. *Discovering Modern Set Theory. II*, Graduate Studies in Math. **18**, Providence: AMS, 1997.

[Va] J. E. Vaughan. *Small uncountable cardinals and topology* // in: *Open Problems in Topology*, ed: J. van Mill and G.M.Reed, Amsterdam: North-Holland, 1990, 195–216.